# How to set emacs frame size by pixels

Tags: frames

I can resize the emacs frame to whatever size by mouse, is there a way that the frame size be set in init.el by pixels? Or anything similar in the window manager?

Comment: See the [manual node on Frame Size and Position](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Size-and-Position.html).  I found this with a [web search for "emacs frame pixels"](https://www.google.com/search?q=emacs+frame+pixels&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb).

Comment: The `default-frame-alist` can be used to come very close, but only pixelwise on OSX with the latest patch in bug number 21415:  https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21415  For exact sizes, adjusting after the fact is necessary with `set-frame-size` using the optional `pixelwise` argument.  I'll put in a request for Emacs on Microsoft Windows later on today.  Most people use `toggle-frame-maximized` or other full-frame arguments in `make-frame` or  the `default-frame-alist`, but if the user wants a specific size that is not full-screen, then `set-frame-size` is the way to go if not OSX

Comment: See also the `initial-frame-alist`:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Initial-Parameters.html

Comment: Per @Dan comment, possible new location [manual node](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Window-Size-X.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have a screen with resolution of 1024X600, but i set the display to 1024X724, here is my solution.

```
(setq frame-resize-pixelwise t)
(set-frame-position (selected-frame) 0 0)
(set-frame-size (selected-frame) 1024 600 t)
```

Answer (score 9):

As of October 13, 2015, Feature request #21415 has been incorporated into the master branch (aka Emacs trunk), such that frame creation may now include a pixel specification -- this includes items such as the `initial-frame-alist`, `default-frame-alist`, and the `make-frame` function.  The git commit identification number is d4fe840df0b5fdb3aed538fae2ced143a471f60a.  It is built-in to the public release of Emacs 25.

Example of usage for the `width` parameter:  `'(width . (text-pixels . 1900))`

Example of usage for the `height` parameter:  `'(height . (text-pixels . 1054))`

Here is an example using `make-frame` -- the font I have chosen is available on OSX 10.6.8 (substitute your own favorite font in the example accordingly):

```lisp
(defun my-example-make-frame ()
"Doc-string."
(interactive)
  (make-frame '((name . "HELLO-WORLD")
                (font . "-*-Courier-normal-normal-normal-*-18-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1")
                (top . 100)
                (left . 100)
                (left-fringe . 8)
                (right-fringe . 8)
                (vertical-scroll-bars . right)
                (cursor-color . "yellow")
                (cursor-type . (bar . 1))
                (background-color . "black")
                (foreground-color . "white")
                (tool-bar-lines . 0)
                (menu-bar-lines . 0)
                (width . (text-pixels . 400))
                (height . (text-pixels . 400)))))
```