# How to make frame-title-format persistent?

Tags: frames

When I set the title for a frame to current buffers filename via `(setq-default frame-title-format '("%b"))` the title often falls back to `"emacs@" system-name`, when the frame is inactive.

I'd expect emacs to keep frame-title, when a frame is inactive, too.

How to keep the title at all times – and only change it, when an other buffer is active? What could cause the unwanted behaviour?

**EDIT:**
Ideal would be, if I could just keep `frame-title-format '("%b")` – but inactive Frames shouldn't revert to `"emacs@" system-name`, but keep the filename from active buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A frame title that is set explicitly by modifying the frame parameters will *not* revert to another name.  I do this when creating a frame;e.g., by passing a parameter of `(name . "HELLO-WORLD")` to the `make-frame` command.  However, it can be done after the frame is already created; e.g., `M-x set-frame-name`.  I do not know how to *persistently* accomplish this objective by using `(setq-default frame-title-format ...)`.

Here is an example using the `make-frame` command:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17354/2287