# Multiple initial buffers in different windows

Tags: buffers, window, start-up

I have Emacs set up to open an initial org mode buffer on startup by

```
(setq initial-buffer-choice "~/Directory/Subdirectory/inital_buffer1.org")
```

Ideally on start up, I would like to open 2 buffers in different windows separated vertically, however. Is there a way to do this? And is there some way of customizing the width of each of these initial buffers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Opening Two Buffers on Startup

You could add a function to `emacs-startup-hook` which switches to the first buffer you want, splits the window, moves to the next window, and switches the second buffer (this is exactly what the function below does). You didn't specify whether the buffers you wanted to display were file buffers or already existing buffers. Here they are created if they don't exist. If you want file buffers use `find-file` instead of `get-buffer-create`.

```
(defun my-setup-initial-window-setup ()
  "Do what I want for initial window setup.
In my case I want to start with 2 windows split side by side."
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "one"))
  (split-window-horizontally)
  (other-window 1)
  (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "two")))

(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook #'my-setup-initial-window-setup)
```

This is the easiest way. You'd just ignore `initial-buffer-choice`. If you want to be very efficient you could make initial buffer choice a function returning to the first buffer you want to see on startup and then use a slightly modified version of the function above.

- Window Width

Your question on buffer width is a separate question. There are already [detailed answers online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987760/how-to-change-size-of-split-screen-emacs-windows) on how to change window width.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much for the tip!

Comment: Hey - quick follow up question you might be able to help with. So I'm using set-frame-size to get my frame the size I want it. I see that by default it sizes by characters/lines. Try as I might I've put (setq frame-resize-pixelwise t) before it but it continues to set the frame size by characters and lines and not by pixel size. Have you run into this problem?

Comment: I never resize my frame other than making it fullscreen, because I only ever use windows so I'm not very familiar with this issue. However, a quick google search pointed me to this link: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16961/how-to-set-emacs-frame-size-by-pixels. It looks promising.

Comment: Mmmmmm, I saw this thread and worked through it but, try as I might, despite adding setq frame-resize-pixelwise to non-nil it continues to adjust my frame by character/lines..... to further complicate the matters, I can only get this to work in GNU Emacs and not on Aquamacs and I'm not sure why. At any rate, thank you very much for the help :)