# How to use make-frame to bring up "maximized windows" like -mm does for the first window (using WSL 2)?

Tags: microsoft-windows, frames

I am running emacs under (Ubuntu under) WSL 2 and I can bring up the first frame maximized (i.e. almost full screen, leaving the Windows "task bar" exposed, the -mm option does that).  I would like to bring up other frames the same way, so that by switching tasks on the task bar, I see only one Emacs frame.  I can do this by creating a window and clicking on the maximize button, but I would like to do it within Emacs (using make-frame) because I layout the emacs windows/buffers based upon the frame real estate and doing it as two steps gets the internal windows slightly the wrong size.

In the old X days, I could do it with geometry frame-parameters, but WSL 2 doesn't seem to respect the top and left parameters and makes a frame where the maximize button is outside the display area so I cannot even click on it without first moving the window and then clicking.  Moreover, I'm not certain that the geometry I am specifying is exactly the right size, which may be exacerbating the problem.

Comment: `make-frame` can take arguments to control how the frame is created:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17354/2287

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `default-frame-alist` controls the frame dimensions. To have any new frame maximized write

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(fullscreen . maximized))
```

in your init.el.
See [the official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Frame-Parameters.html) for details.

Comment: The documentation now lists many more parameters than the list time I played with frames.

Answer (score 3):

@matteol tells you how to get the effect you want for all frames, by default.

To answer just your question about creating a frame with `make-frame`, either of these may help (they don't need to be interactive):

```lisp
(defun my-make-frame ()
  "..."
  (interactive)
  (let ((default-frame-alist  '((fullscreen . maximized))))
    (make-frame)))

(defun my-make-frame ()
  "..."
  (interactive)
  (let ((default-frame-alist  ()))
    (make-frame '((fullscreen . maximized)))))
```

The value of `default-frame-alist` supplements whatever frame-parameters alist you pass to `make-frame`.