# make-frame - not full screen mode

Tags: frames

Linux Mint 20.2

Emacs 27.1

To start Emacs in full screen mode in my init.el I use this:

```
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'toggle-frame-maximized t)
```

Nice.

But when I want to start new frame by this command

```
M-x make-frame
```

The new frame is not in full scree mode

Comment: Seems to be a [duplicate](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/66478/how-to-use-make-frame-to-bring-up-maximized-windows-like-mm-does-for-the-firs).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use make-frame to bring up "maximized windows" like -mm does for the first window (using WSL 2)?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/66478/how-to-use-make-frame-to-bring-up-maximized-windows-like-mm-does-for-the-firs)